# Is the logic of the table correct?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have recently come across an SQL table with the following structure:

int Id,

```
INT Id,
NVARCHAR(50) ItemNumber,
INT January,
INT February,
...,
INT December,
INT Year
```

This integer columns are the number of sales for the specified colomn name month and year. I am interested whether this logic is appropriate for an SQL table. Wouldn't it be more professional to create another table, where we can store for example months and have a reference to that table from the previous table, *monthId* for example and here have another column *Count*?

Comment: Yes. A properly _normalised_ able has a single `monthid` column and a value column

Comment: That *appears* to break Normal Form, if that's what you're asking and (if it isn't a Data Warehouse) I'm not sure why you'd need to store such data (such, being that's aggregated); it could be derived by querying your source tables. Tables like these tends to become "out of date" unless frequently updated

Comment: Which normal form exactly does it break?

Comment: [Normal Form](https://www.studytonight.com/dbms/database-normalization.php)

Comment: Never mind. I thought you were asking what normal form was.

Comment: It breaks [1NF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_normal_form). It has repeating groups `January`,`February`,etc is a repeating group.

Comment: Thanks a lot :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I sure hope the `year` column is for the year, and not, say, some total for the year.

Your intuition is correct.  I would be inclined to simply structure this as:

```
create table <whatever> as (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    itemCode nvarchar(50),
    yyyymm date not null,
    amount int  -- amount is an arbitrary name for the value column
);
```

Note that I think that item**Number** is a really bad name for something that is a string.

You can guarantee one row per month with constraints:

```
create table <whatever> as (
    id int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    itemCode nvarchar(50),
    yyyymm date not null,
    amount int,
    constraint chk_whatever_yyyymm (day(yyyymm) = 1),
    constraint unq_whatever_yyyymm_itemcode unique (itemCode, yyyymm)
);
```

You *could* use a `monthid` column with a separate lookup table.  However, a constraint fixing the date to the first of the month means that the month can be represented as a `date`, directly enabling all the date functions.

Comment: *"One major problem is the lack of a "year" column in the table."* Yes it does; that's the last column it the OP's table; which they defined as *"`INT Year`"*.

Comment: @Larnu . . . Interesting.  I wonder if that is the total for the year or if that is actually the year.

Comment: One would *hope* the latter, but you're right it could well be the former; which ***would*** be a problem. I think that an explanation of that would help the answer here.

Comment: Yes that is not the total, but the year of the months, e.g. 2018.